Apply Phase Shift Using FFT and complex exponential
I would like to apply a phase shift by multiplying by a complex exponential in Fourier space, then taking the inverse transform. I've almost got it, but it's a factor of 2 off. I want the phase shift to be $\pi/4$, but it's showing a shift of $\pi/2$. What am I doing wrong and why? I don't just want to insert a 2 just to make it work.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
Fs = 1000  # Sampling frequency (Hz)
T = 1.0 / Fs  # Sampling period (s)
t = np.arange(0, 1, T)  # Time vector (1 second of data)

f0 = 50  # Frequency of sine wave (Hz)
phi = np.pi / 4  # Phase shift (in radians)

# Generate the original sine wave
x = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * t)

# Compute the FFT of the sine wave
X = np.fft.fft(x)

# Create a complex exponential for phase shift
n = np.arange(len(t))  # Frequency index
phase_shift = np.exp(1j * phi * n) # Complex exponential

# Apply the phase shift in the frequency domain
X_shifted = X  * phase_shift

# Compute the inverse FFT to get the shifted sine wave
x_shifted = np.fft.ifft(X_shifted)

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t[:40], x[:40], label="Original Sine Wave",marker='o')
plt.title("Original Sine Wave")
plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t[:40], np.real(x_shifted)[:40], label="Phase-shifted Sine Wave", color="orange",marker='o')
plt.title(f"Phase-shifted Sine Wave (Phase = {phi} rad)")
plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.grid(True)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



Recall the time shift property of the Fourier Transform:
$$\mathcal{F}\{x(t - t_0)\} =   e^{-j\omega t_0}X(\omega )$$

n = np.arange(len(t)) is wrong. You need the indices of the frequency bins used by the FFT: n = np.fft.fftfreq(len(t), 1 / Fs)

When you multiply your FFT by np.exp(-1j * phi * n), you're introducing a phase shift that increases linearly with frequency. At your sine wave's frequency ($50 \tt{Hz}$), the phase shift is $50\pi/4$. Since phase is modulo $2\pi$, that's $50\pi/4 \text{ mod } 2\pi = \pi/2 $, resulting in what you're seeing.


You need to have a constant phase shift:
phase_shift = np.exp(-1j * phi/f0 * n):


But in the plot, each blue peak is $\pi/2$ away from the nearest orange peak, no matter what sign of the phase I choose. In other words, a quarter of a cycle off. But $\pi/4$ is an eighth of a cycle.

Yep, you're absolutely correct. I edited my answer, let me know if that makes sense.

Thank you so much for explaining! Going back and forth between time and frequency space has so many gotchas. I also didn't know about the fftfreq function. I'll be using that!

no problem! Glad I could help ;)
